# jQuery ajax POST data is empty on the server for some clients

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I encountered a very peculiar problem and none of the answers I found here solves it.

On SOME clients (IE7, IE8) when I post the data using jQuery Ajax, such as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl"~/User.svc/GetUserListForCity") %>',
    data: '{"city":' + cityId + '}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: processList,
    error: showErrorAlert
});
```

The error I am getting:

> "The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true)."

However when I attempt to use Fiddler to look at the data, the request is successful.

The server is IIS and the request is served by WCF Web Service (webHttpBinding). Removing contentType to allow defaults is being rejected by the server as it expects JSON. 
Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: I messed up the format of the javascript code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. look's like you are sending  data object is wrong

```
data: {"city": cityId }, // If cityID is a string this should do
```

OR

```
data: '{"city":"' + cityId + '"}',
```

There might also be a problem with the way you are sending the url.. Try using a absolute path and check if that works..

Comment: The code works for most of the clients, so it must be correct. I forgot to add that request is coming form inline frame. Could that be a problem?