# AJAX data returns empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the code at the bottom that get's a name from a hidden input type, and I want to send that to a php page but the ajax data returns empty. The console.log on line 4 returns the value, but the console.log on the bottom returns empty. I tried changing the way I assign data inside the ajax call according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607500/jquery-ajax-post-data-is-empty-on-the-server-for-some-clients) but this didn't change anything. Any ideas?

```
$('.uploadImage input[name="userImage"]').on("change", function(){
    var image = new FormData($('input[name="userImage"]')[0].files[0]);
    var name = $('.hidden').attr("name");
    console.log(name);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax-image.php",
        processData: false,
        data: name,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(name);
        }
    });
});
```

ajax-image.php

```
 <?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$dir = ("../user_img/".$name."");
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir,0700);         
    }
 ?>
```

I added the ; at that line

Feel free to edit both of my code's, I really don't have and idea what to do next

Comment: closing part is wrong on last before line change `})` to `});`

Comment: please show includes/ajax-image.php source to make your question clearer

Comment: I think `success: function(data){console.log(name);}` should be `success: function(data){console.log(data);}`

Comment: i put data instead of name and no result

Comment: You are missing the curly bracket in the **data: {}**

Comment: must the data have curly bracket's if only one 'thing' is sent with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processData option here is not needed remove that and try again

Comment: it turns out you were partly right. i removed processData but i also had to change the way i asign the data. the correct way was data:{"name": name}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.uploadImage input[name="userImage"]').on("change", function(){
    var image = new FormData($('input[name="userImage"]')[0].files[0]);
    var name = $('.hidden').attr("name");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax-image.php",
        processData: false,
        data: {"name": name },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});


 <?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$dir = ("../user_img/".$name."");
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir,0700);         
    }

echo $name;

 ?>
```

Comment: @gogo_rulez try echoing something from PHP side

Comment: have you checked in firebug console? is there any error showing?

Comment: did the AJAX post the data?

Comment: if inside the ajax-image.php file i change the dir from     
$dir = ("../user_img/".$name."");    to   
$dir = ("../user_img/name");

then the folder "name" is made

Comment: `("../user_img/{$name}");`

Comment: so, i guess that ajax calls the ajax-image file, but it doesn't send any data - or should i say - it sends empty data

Comment: i tried you code, but nothing happens. a folder doesn't get created that way